# Changing the User Title

Tags: users, 7

I did some searching here, but I couldn't find exactly what I was looking for. Is there a template.php function that I can add to change the content title (not the `<head>` page title) of a user to be a field created after-the-fact (like a first name or the last name field)? If it can't be a function, maybe some type of 'if' statement to wrap around the content title output to check if it's a user page and then output the fields would probably work.

Comment: Maybe you could try http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle + token ?

Comment: refineo: users are not nodes, so I guess that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [Real Name](https://www.drupal.org/project/realname) module, it's worked very nicely for me. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows the administrator to choose fields from the user profile that will be used to add a "real name" element (method) to a user object. Hook_user is used to automatically add this to any user object that is loaded. It will also optionally set all nodes and comments to show this name.

Answer (score 6):

The page title of the user profile page (like example.com/user/1) is generated by [format_username()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/format_username/7). If you want to control the username everywhere it occurs in the site, you can implement [hook_username_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_username_alter/7) in a custom module.

If you just want to change title on the user profile page, you could add THEMENAME_preprocess_page to your template.php to override `$variables['title']`. An example (untested code):

```
<?php
/**
 * Preprocess function for page.tpl.php.
 * Replace 'THEMENAME' with the name of your theme.
 */
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // Only act when the first part of the url equals 'user', the second
  // part is a number and the third part is empty.
  $arg = arg();
  if ($arg[0] == 'user' && is_numeric($arg[1]) && empty($arg[2])) {
    // Do stuff to create the desired username and set the $title variable for the template.
    $variables['title'] = $variables['firstname'] . ' ' . $variables['lastname'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Appreciate the insight on this - little new to Drupal, any further help you might be able to give? Thanks.

Comment: I love to help, but it helps if you have specific questions I can answer. By the way, I would definitely check out the module rfay recommends in his answer. His advice has never let me down.

Comment: Hi @marcvangend Thanks for the response. I guess I'm looking for the actual template.php function that I could use to overrite the page title just on the user profile page with a field I created in the Accounts & Settings area in Drupal 7 (for example, first_name and last_name). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not talking about overriding a theme function, I'm talking about overriding template variables. I understand that the lingo can be a bit confusing sometimes... I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi @marcvangend - Sorry, I think we were lost in translation there (my fault). Yes, I was looking for overriding a template variable with what you are talking about above - but unfortunately I get an error - so I revised the parenthesis a bit and don't get an error, but it doesn't seem to be overriding the page title at all:

http://pastebin.com/HPsrKkAr

Thanks!

Comment: Zach, the code on pastebin is fine, except for one little ampersand (`&`) character in `function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {`. Without the ampersand, the $variables array is only edited inside the scope of the function, so your changes have no effect outside your function. (See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php for more info.) [With the ampersand](http://pastebin.com/Xe0Q4fcK), it works.

Comment: Ah great! Sorry about that - my fault. Now to actually render a user_profile variable, I tried using: `$variables['title'] = $variable[$user_profile['field_user_last_name'][0]];` but I'm not sure if that's even close. Any suggestions on that? Thanks!

Comment: Try printing out the $variables to see what's in there. Install devel module and add dsm($variables); to your function.

Comment: hook_username_alter worked perfectly!